ant design time picker validation issue with zod resolver
im facing an issue. i use react hook form with ant design input fields. such as timepicker,date picker and normal input.. but the issue is ant design timepicker
gives an time object when we select time: example:
but the issue is how can i validate this time using zod resolver. im trying too much approch but not working.. currently im doing that 
its help to pretend undifiend. but i need something to validate it more better way. because i cannot do anything here for refine.. i need to validate openingTime and closingTime. how can i solve this guys. if i use here z.string({}) instead of object then when i select time its gives me an error called: expected string gives object do you have any solustion guys? thank you

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, don't post code as screenshots
